# Запрос с условием, есть ли связь со всеми строками связанной таблицы

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как вывести только те данные исполнителей, которые входят во все группы?
На данный момент 3-и группы. Если входит в две или одну группу, то надо исключить, а если в три, то для каждой группы включить в выборку. Выборку упорядочить по номеру группы и по статусу исполнителей. Пробую так:

```
SELECT kto.fio AS "Исполнители заказа 1", statusss.statustext AS "Статус исполнителей", groupmember.nomgr AS "Группа"
FROM kto 
INNER JOIN groupmember ON kto.codmember = groupmember.codmember 
INNER JOIN statusss ON kto.codstatus = statusss.codstatus 
ORDER BY statusss.statustext, groupmember.nomgr
```

Но выводит все данные:

[image: Вывод]

Comment: А зачем group by?

Comment: ответа я не знаю, ну я убрал))

Comment: Куда убрали? По условию это сортировка, order by должен быть вместо group by.

Comment: Что с предложеннын ответом, он неверен или не соответствует поставленной задаче?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT 
    fio AS "Исполнители заказа 1", 
    statustext AS "Статус исполнителей", 
    nomgr AS "Группа" 
FROM (
    SELECT
        k.fio, s.statustext, g.nomgr,
        count (1) over (partition by k.fio) groups
    FROM kto k
    INNER JOIN groupmember g ON g.codmember = k.codmember 
    INNER JOIN statusss    s ON s.codstatus = k.codstatus 
    )
WHERE groups = 3
ORDER BY nomgr, statustext
```